# dynamic ng-model for md-datepicker in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I dynamically add md-datepicker for date of birth to form by below code:

```
$scope.infData = [];
            $scope.addInf = function() {
            if ($scope.infData.length < 4) {
            $scope.infData.push({});
            }
        };
```

and my html is like below :

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-3"
ng-repeat="d in infData | limitTo: 4"
ng-value="d.value"
ng-class="{'md-align-top-left': $index==1}">
<md-input-container flex>
<label>infant D.O.B</label>
<md-datepicker
onkeydown="return false"
name="myDate{{$index}}"
ng-model="inf[$index==1].date"
md-hide-icons="all"
ng-required="true"
md-current-view="year"
md-min-date="ctrl.minDate"
md-max-date="ctrl.maxDate"
md-open-on-focus="true"
ng-messages>
</md-datepicker>
```

and they are limited to 4 . My goal is get the vlaue of date as below that I did succesfully for normal datepicker :

```
if ($scope.inf.dateString = moment($scope.inf.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {
    $scope.list.push(this.inf.dateString);
```

now my questions is :
1)how I can asing value to this date picker just when $index=1(not show value if this date picker not push)?
2)the value is always as max-date as today (any date that choose)?
3)I'm sure my `ng-model=inf[$index==1].date` is wrong but how I can make it dynamic ?
4)How to reset value after submit `$scope.inf = ""; & $scope.inf = {};` not working and value stay be there

any idea and help will save my day.
Ps:
I read most of stackover question about `angularjs ng-model inside nested ng-repeat` but non of them work for me

Answer (score 0):

Cant really undestand the question, but maybe you want this:

```
$scope.addInf = function(index) {
    if ($scope.infData.length < 4) {
       $scope.infData.push({
         date: (index == 1 ? 'Some value you want' : '')
       });
    }
};
```

Change your datepicker HTML

```
ng-model="d.date"
```

And your add button HTML

```
<button ng-if="$last" ng-click="addInf($index)">myBtn</button>
```

Assuming that the button is inside the repeated div